# Changing from Full Trust to Medium Trust

Tags: asp.net, .net, code-access-security, medium-trust, full-trust

I have an ASP.NET website which run under .NET3.5 full trust for years. Now I am moving it to another hosting provider. I changed the project to .NET 4.0 and the provider is using medium trust.

This results in a load of security exceptions.

How can I easily find out which pieces of code are causing these exceptions? The security exception itself hardly gives any usefull information (besides stack trace). I need information like what kind of security-permission is required, which class or method was that permission needed for.

I was trying to find permview.exe: did not succeed. I've read that .NET4.0 does not use perview.exe anymore.

So basically I am looking for some suggestions and a good place to start. Anyone?

Comment: The `SecurityException` details (as returned by the exception's `ToString()` method) should really be giving you sufficient information for troubleshooting purposes.  How are you capturing the exception information?